# complex limit,. theoretical justification for beeing able to calculate the limit this way

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a complex limit I have to calculate. I know how to calculate it, but I would like a theoretical justification for why we can calculate it this way. Look at this:

I want to calculate:

$\lim_{z \rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\cos
(z)\cdot(z^3-z^2-2z)-\sin(z)\cdot(3z^2-2z-2) }{(z^3-z^2-2z)^2}$

I expand the Taylor series for sin and cos, and get:

$\lim_{z \rightarrow 0}\dfrac{(1-z^2/2+z^4/4!+...)\cdot(z^3-z^2-2z)-(z-z^3/3!+z^5/5!+...)\cdot(3z^2-2z-2)}{(z^3-z^2-2z)^2}$

$=\lim_{z \rightarrow 0}\dfrac{z^2(-1+2)+c_1z^3+c_4z^4+c_5*z^6+....}{(z^3-z^2-2z)^2}=1/4$

In the last i used that in $z^2$, has 2 has exponent, and this is the smallest of z both in the numerator and the denominator.So I can divide by $z^2$ in the numerator and the denominator and let z og to zero.

**But there are a lot of sketchy things with this calculation:**

1. When going from the second to the third expression, I make a new power series, am I allowed to do this? Do I know that it behaves well and converges?
2. When evaluating the limit after i divide by $z^2$ I get the power series 
   $1+c_1z+c_2z^2+...$, and I evaluate it at zero, I am not supposed to do this, I am supposed to let it og to 0?, and in order to say that the limit is the same as the value at 0 I need to know that it is continuous, do I know that?
3. The Taylor series for sin and cos, are defined around 0. But my expression does not exist at zero, does this create any problems when I later evaluate the new power series at 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When going from the second to the third expression, I make a new power series, am I allowed to do this? Do I know that it behaves well and converges?

Yes. All functions involved in the numerator are entire functions, so

$$f(z) = (z^3-z^2-2z)\cos z - (3z^2-2z-2)\sin z$$

is an entire function, and its Taylor series converges to $f$ in the entire plane. You could, if you wanted, compute all coefficients explicitly, but it suffices to compute only the first nonzero coefficient.

> When evaluating the limit after i divide by $z^2$ I get the power series $1+c_1z+c_2z^2+\dotsc$, and I evaluate it at zero,

That's fine if you already know what a removable singularity is.

> I am not supposed to do this, I am supposed to let it go to $0$?,

That's what you need to do if you haven't yet heard of removable singularities.

> and in order to say that the limit is the same as the value at $0$ I need to know that it is continuous, do I know that?

A convergent power series always has a continuous sum, so you do know that it is continuous.

> The Taylor series for $\sin$ and $\cos$, are defined around $0$. But my expression does not exist at zero, does this create any problems when I later evaluate the new power series at $0$?

No, it does not create problems. The singularity at $0$ is removable - that is what the existence of the limit shows - and thus in a sense artificial. The cancelling of $z^2$ in the numerator and denominator leads to an expression that defines a holomorphic function $g$ in a neighbourhood $U$ of $0$, and by the rules of arithmetic, it coincides with the original in $U\setminus\{0\}$, so the original has a limit at $0$, and the value of the limit is simply the value $g(0)$, since $g$ is holomorphic, hence continuous, in $U$.

Comment: Thanks, I just have two things I need to get cleared up. The first thing is what you write in the second paragraph: "That's fine if you already know what a removable singularity is." Here I have a holomorphic function that I divide by $z^2$. Do you mean that the new function have a removable singularity, and hence the value which I get after the algebraic manipulation must be that removable singularity? How do I if so know that it is a removable singularity?, I need to show that the function is bounded in order to have this?

Comment: The second thing is "A convergent power series always has a continuous sum, so you do know that it is continuous." How do I know it converges, and doesnt it only hold in the radius of convergence? I know that if I have a holomorphic function and divide it by $z^2$, it is holomorphic. So I know that $1+c_1z+c_2z^2+...$ must converge pointwise for each z, but I am not inside a radius of convergence now, so how do I get unfirom convergence and hence continuity?

Comment: You get the removability directly from the algebraic manipulations. If you have a quotient $$f(z) = \frac{(z-z_0)^k\cdot g(z)}{(z-z_0)^k\cdot h(z)},$$ you know that $$f(z) = \frac{g(z)}{h(z)}$$ for $z \neq z_0$. Now, if $h(z_0) \neq 0$, you can read off that $z_0$ is a removable singularity of $f$, and it is removed by setting $f(z_0) = \frac{g(z_0)}{h(z_0)}$. That is what you do here, with $z_0 = 0$ and $k = 2$. The boundedness near $z_0$ follows.

Comment: Concerning the second, yes, you only have continuity of the sum of a power series in the region of convergence. But the Taylor series of a holomorphic function with centre $a$ always converges (at least) in the largest disk around $a$ contained in the domain of the function. Here, we have an entire function, so the power series converges on all of $\mathbb{C}$. If $f(z)$ is entire, and $f$ has a zero of order $\geqslant k$ at $z_0$, then the function $\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^k}$ a priori is known to be holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{z_0\}$, but it has a removable singularity in $z_0$, so

Comment: $\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^k}$ is also an entire function.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have one **$last$** question, I hope that is ok.I must admit that it is difficult for me to truly understand how to use the removable singularity argument here. I have collected the argument with continuity etc:, could you please check if it is ok, enough? :When starting with the first expression, we know that numerator and denominator is holomorphic, so they both have power series which converges everywhere, hence we get expression 2, collected together this gives expression 3.[more]

Comment: Now we know that the numerator in expression 3 is holomorphic and converges everywhere. We divide the numerator and denominator by $z^2$ , $z^2$ is an holomorpic function, so we know that the numerator must be holomorphic wherever it is defined, where it is defined algebra gives us that the value must be $1+c_1z+c_2z^2....$, so we know that this function converges everywhere except 0(is this correct?), but if we look at the expression it also converges at 0(value=1). [more]

Comment: So the expression $1+c_1z+c_2z^2....$must be an entire function, simply because it is a power series that converges everywhere.And hence it is continuous so to get the limit value as z approaches 0, we simply plug in the value and get 1. (The treatment of the denominator is trivial).

Comment: Well, I'd put it the other way round, the series $1 + c_1 z + c_2 z^2 + \dotsc$ converges everywhere because it's the Taylor series of an entire function, namely $$\frac{(z^3-z^2-2z)\cos z - (3z^2 - 2z - 2)\sin z}{z^2}.$$ The numerator is evidently entire, and since it has a zero of order two at $0$, dividing by $z^2$ gives us an entire function again.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluating your limit with $z$ replaced by real $x$ using l'Hôpital confirms your result 1/4. Now you need something to allow you to extend this to the limit for complex $z$.

Edit: I did some digging about l'Hôpital's rule for the complex case. Although it does not always apply in the complex situation, the present case is all right and it gives the result 1/4.
D.S. CarterThe American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 65, No. 4, Apr., 1958. 
http://www.solitaryroad.com/c604.html